# I am getting sigsegv error for this code

Tags: string, sorting, stl, segmentation-fault

Why am I getting SIGSEGV run time error when I am submitting this on codechef ?
Problem Code : CHEFCHR

Link: https://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/17448920

Comment: `s.length()-3` will wrap around to a very large number if the length of `s` is less than 3.

Comment: pass code not link - try to extract SSCCE: "Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example: http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 0):

This code would work on some occasions, which could be misleading.

When you have hard-coded numbers that you compare against in your code you are setting yourself against a limited set of input data. When the input is out of that limit it will mess with your code flow.

Know that SIGSEGV is in general an error that you see when you are accessing a memory location out of bound.